# don't know why my cursorForObjectInConnection returns null?

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js, relaymodern

I am having this error on response:

> Cannot return null for non-nullable field TodoEdge.cursor.

This is my mutation code:

```
  mutateAndGetPayload: async ({text}, context) => {
      let newTodo = new TodoModel({ text, _creatorUserId: context.user._id });
      await newTodo.save(); 
      return {newTodo}; 
  },
  outputFields: {
    todoEdge: {
      type: GraphQLTodoEdge,
      resolve: async ({newTodo}, args,context) => {
        const todos = await getTodosByUserContext(context.user._id, 'any');
        console.log("cursorForObjectInConnection = ",cursorForObjectInConnection(todos, newTodo)) // this logs null?
        return {
          cursor: cursorForObjectInConnection(todos, newTodo),
          node: newTodo,
        };
      },
    },
```

todos and newTodo is retreived from mongoose database. I think I am following this relevant [todo-modern sample](https://github.com/relayjs/relay-examples/blob/master/todo-modern/data/schema.js#L134) properly. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try following:

1) Get todos from your DB like

```
const todos = await Todo.find({});
```

You can get todos for a specific user as per your Todo Schema. Todo.find({ userid: context.user._id});

2) once you get your todos then get cursor:

```
const cursor = offsetToCursor(todos.length);
```

This worked for me. Give it a try.